# How to delete cells on UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I created a button on every cell that onClick let the users delete a cell of my UICollectionView, where I initialize the cell I used the following code in order to pass the indexPath.item to the button method:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];



    // Configure the cell
    FidelityProducts *item = _feedItems[indexPath.item];
    NSLog(@"index dell'item:%ld", (long)indexPath.item);

    cell.deleteProduct.tag = indexPath.item;
    NSLog(@"TAG ASSEGNATO AL BOTTONE: %d",cell.deleteProduct.tag);
    [cell.deleteProduct addTarget:self action:@selector(DeleteProductFromArray:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}
```

Then on the `DeleteProductFromArray` I created the following logic in order to delete the cells:

```
- (void)DeleteProductFromArray:(UIButton *)button {

    [_feedItems removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];

    //check for the Column (can be 0 or 1)
    if(button.tag % 2 == 0)
    {
        IndexColumn = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        IndexColumn = 1;
    }

    //check for the Row
    if(button.tag > 1)
    {
        IndexRow = button.tag/2;
    }
    if(button.tag <= 1)
    {
        IndexRow = 0;
    }
    NSLog(@"button column =%d", IndexColumn);
    NSLog(@"button row =%d", IndexRow);

    [self.customCollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:IndexColumn inSection:IndexRow]]];

}
```

Now, I know that this will cause problem because the button tags aren't updated when I remove an item from my NSMutableArray but I just need to know why The first time that I try to delete a Cell the number 1 and 2 are cancelled but if I click on a cell > 3 the app crashes with the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete item 0 from section 2, but there are only 1 sections before the update
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stupid.
All the button logic was useless, I forgot to check number of section, they're always 0.
Changed

```
[self.customCollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:IndexColumn inSection:IndexRow]]];
```

To:

```
 [self.customCollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:button.tag inSection:0]]];
```

And everything worked as expected..